# Extracting Datas with JSoup

Tags: user-interface, jsoup

Even though I've look through so many answers to this question, I still do not know how to make this happen on my program.

Basically, I want to get the data from this website -> http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/ahri

and then, from this specific data table

```
<table id="champion_info-lower" style="background-color:#041424;box-shadow:0 2px 5px black, inset 0 7px 5px -5px black;text-align:center;padding:0 1em;border-spacing:0;width:90%;margin:0 auto;">
```

I want to extract the numbers for the statistics such as health, health regen, attack damage, attack speed into the instance variable in my class.

So how do I do this?

Can you guys show the specific code, not just by words, because I still do not understand how this is working and this program being made right now is my first program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Usually, people including myself, are reluctant to provide code if the the person who asks hasn't shown any of their own attempts first, but since this one can be quite tricky and mostly comes down to how to use Jsoup and not programming in general, I'll provide an answer with example code that should give you the results that you desire. Though bear in mind, you should practice your general programming and provide examples of what code you have done so far instead of just ask others to provide the code for you!

---

**Select certain elements with ID**

You can use the CSS-selector to select the `table` element with the `id="champion_info-lower"`
using the syntax `#id`, as done below on the `<span id="Abilities">` element

```
Element e = doc.select("span#Abilities").first();
System.out.println(e.text());
```

which prints out `Abilities`. This can be used to get the values in the table.

---

**Splitting up the values into variables**

I don't want to hand you a complete solution, but this might be hard to explain without showing some working code. If you look at the HTML that contains the table that you are interested in, you see that you can select the right part only by using the following selector syntax for the `td` elements that contain the data that we want to parse.

```
Elements table = doc.select("table#champion_info-lower td:eq(1) table td");
```

Further observing at the HTML reveals that the value for the health is presented in the sibling element to the element that contains the text "Health". If we check each element in the table for the text "Health", we know that the next following will be the one we are looking for. Since we have selected only the `td` elements, this should now be easy.

```
String health = "Health: ";
for (Element e : table) {
    if (e.text().equals("Health")) {
        health += table.get(table.indexOf(e) + 1).text();
    }
}
System.out.println(health);
```

1. Check all the elements in the table.
2. If it has the text "Health", assign the value of the next element to `string health`.

This will output

```
Health: 380 (+80)
```

Figuring out how to get the rest of the values should be a piece of cake!

Try some code of your own before you continue, and I strongly recommend that you use the [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) API to find out how to use it, especially the [Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) class and the [FAQ](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) on how to use the selector.

Comment: THANK YOU!but how did you find out this part         "table#champion_info-lower td:eq(1) table td" like I found out table#champion_info-lower but I did not know this td:eq (1)

Comment: I basically do not know what to put inside the select method to really get the String I want. Is there a way for me to learn this?

Comment: Yes, of course there is. If you follow the links I provided, you will found out exactly what :eq(1) means, or :gt(3) etc. does to your selector!